# ASP.NET-Saving Special Characters to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, special-characters

Please tell me how can save a string with special characters to DB.Special characters may contatin single `quotes/double quotes`  etc.. I am using ASP.NET with C#

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized queries.

http://aspnet101.com/aspnet101/tutorials.aspx?id=1

When rendering to the client, you should also use Server.HtmlEncode() to convert characters which have special meaning in HTML to numeric character references.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without much details. But usually the best bet is parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Eventhough i saved in the DB.I need to display this back to a text box.Then the page is breaking. Ex: I have saved Student name as Ani"s and when i am displayin gthis

How to get rid of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you encoding the value when you write it out?  (Server.HtmlEncode(value))

Answer (score 0):

```
Using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
    Using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FOO (col) VALUES (@arg)"))
    {
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arg",SpecialCharsString);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Reading it out should not be breaking your output at all, if it is, its not the database code doing it.

Answer (score 0):

(Server.HtmlEncode(value)) worked !