# ASP.NET-Saving Special Acent Characters to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, special-characters

When I try to save:
7 test úüãáâàçéêíõóô  áéíñóúü¿¡
.. to my database, it saves as:
7 test �������������  ���������
see row 24.

[image]

However as you can see in the DB, I'm able to store characters like this, see for 23, I manually updated this record.

I read:
[ASP.NET-Saving Special Characters to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279991/asp-net-saving-special-characters-to-database)
.. however I cannot htmlencode everything. Are they any other options here?

Comment: how are you trying to save to your database? some code might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out where things are going wrong. For example, you might have all these steps to consider:

- Is your schema set up correctly?
- Are you receiving data correctly from the client?
- Are you processing the data correctly?
- Are you saving the data correctly?
- Are you fetching the data correctly?
- Are you serving the data correctly?

It's *vital* that you work out a way of diagnosing each step independently. Log the values at every point, in a way which you can *prove* can handle non-ASCII characters. Then you can see *exactly* where your data is being corrupted.

If it's not something within ASP.NET itself, I'd then suggest you create a short but complete *console* application which does nothing but try to save the data. You can then concentrate on getting that working with none of the friction you get through writing a web app... and you can also post that program here, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that is either a **VARCHAR** or **TEXT** column? Try using **NVARCHAR** or **NTEXT**.

Comment: I do not think that matters. As you can see in the image, the record above contains the accents.